# Pricing of DynamoDB continuous backups

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

The [DynamoDB's pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/provisioned/) contains the following text explaining how much storing **continuous backups** (a.k.a. PITR - point-in-time recovery) costs:

> DynamoDB charges for PITR based on the size of each DynamoDB table (table data and local secondary indexes) on which it is enabled. DynamoDB monitors the size of your PITR-enabled tables continuously throughout the month to determine your backup charges and continues to bill you until you disable PITR on each table.

This seems to say that that the user is charged for continuous backups based on the size of the table they are enabled on - not the size of the backup stored. It means that if a user continuously modifies existing data instead of adding new data, Amazon may need huge amounts of storage to store 35 days worth of modifications, space for which the user does not pay. That doesn't make sense to me - I suspect their pricing needs to correspond to the size of the backup, not the table - but this is not claimed in the above text or in any of its similar variants I found on Amazon's site.

So my question is - how does Amazon charge for continuous-backup storage? By the table size, or by the backup size (i.e., the amount of changes)? Is this documented anywhere?

Curiously, I couldn't find any other source on the web which discusses this question.
I found many slightly-modified versions of the above text copied to all sorts of tutorials, but none of them give any example of answers my question. It's as if nobody really cares how much this feature will cost before they start using it :-)

Answer (score 8):

#### Pricing

Your assumptions are correct, and it is of course the price of the table which you pay for. This means that PITR is extremely cost-effective when comparing it to taking multiple on-demand backups. Moreover, PITR also lets you restore to any point in time in the previous 35 days.

#### But How?

How is it done, it's simply smarts from the DynamoDB team, which uses S3 and snapshotting to store your backups. Learn more from this [re:Invent presentation](https://youtu.be/yvBR71D0nAQ?t=2041) which goes into further details.

Comment: I don't see how "smarts" can explain this. Imagine that I have a table with just 1000 items, and I keep writing to these same items over and over, rewriting each item once per second. Now I turn on continuous backups, and DynamoDB needs to save 1000 items per second - that's 3 billion items in 35 days - and I pay just for storing 1000 items.
The only possibility I can think of is that in DynamoDB writes are so expensive, that even if a user does this Amazon doesn't lose money.

Comment: Amazon are customer obsessed. I don't think it should be an end users worry if something is profitable or not. The answer I posted is the correct answer, regardless if Amazon are losing money or not.

Answer (score -1):

The pricing model seems to be clearly stated in your quote, being based on the size of the table. An on-demand backup can easily have its size estimated based on the size of the table, but in the absence of details as to the implementation of continuous backups, it seems that the uncertainty as to the total backup size is taken into account when setting the price at double the price of on-demand backup storage, perhaps with the help of analytical analysis to determine the usual/average levels of activity.

Comment: It's not exactly "clearly stated" - it uses phrases like "DynamoDB monitors the size of your PITR-enabled tables continuously throughout the month", which suggests my interpretation, but isn't exactly an accurate formula. So because I think this pricing doesn't make sense, I was hoping maybe somebody from Amazon or even just a user who saw the actual cost can say that - yes, despite not making sense, this is really the pricing.